# hammer.js swipe android 2.3.5 not working

Tags: javascript, android, swipe, hammer.js

I'd like to include hammer.js in my phonegap / cordova app.

Version: Hammer.JS - v1.0.10 - 2014-03-28

But it seems that the example found here:

```
http://rawgithub.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/examples/carousel.html
```

is not working on my Huawei U8850 Android 2.3.5 device.
The problem: swipe events are not fired as expected.

Only one of about twenty tries are successfull.

Dragging works fine - I had to drag the pages over the mid point to get to the next page.

Tested with stock browser, opera mobile and with a cordova app.

For the cordova app I have added some debug output in hammer.js:

```
    handler : function swipeGesture(ev, inst) {
        if(ev.eventType == EVENT_END) {
            // max touches
            if(ev.touches.length < inst.options.swipe_min_touches ||
                ev.touches.length > inst.options.swipe_max_touches) {
                console.warn(' return');  // this is not the problem 
                return;
            }

            // when the distance we moved is too small we skip this gesture
            // or we can be already in dragging
            if(ev.velocityX > inst.options.swipe_velocity ||
                ev.velocityY > inst.options.swipe_velocity) {
                // trigger swipe events
                console.log('IS TRIGGERED VX: ' + ev.velocityX + '  inst.options.swipe_velocity: ' + inst.options.swipe_velocity);
                inst.trigger(this.name, ev);
                inst.trigger(this.name + ev.direction, ev);
            } else {
                console.log('NOT TRIGGERED VX: ' + ev.velocityX + '  inst.options.swipe_velocity: ' + inst.options.swipe_velocity);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the logcat output:

```
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
IS TRIGGERED VX: 0.9742769115007959  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
SWIPE RIGHT
NOT TRIGGERED VX: 0  inst.options.swipe_velocity: 0.7
```

interesting: the velocity is not only too slow to trigger the event, it is zero most of the times.